# Работа Phaser-а из concurrent

Tags: java, concurrency

Как, в данном задании, Paser понимает, что нити являются его участниками?

Вызвав метод arriveAndAwaitAdvance(), он присоединяет нить, в которой вызван, к пасеру в состоянии прибыла на барьер?

Paser понимет, что нити являются его участниками, за счет методов arriveAndAwaitAdvance и arrive?

Без их вызова в данной задаче он будет пустой?

```
package com.javarush.test.level28.lesson10.home01;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    characters.add(new Plant());
    characters.add(new Plant());
    characters.add(new Zombie());
    characters.add(new Zombie());
    characters.add(new Zombie());
    start(characters);
}

private static boolean isEveryoneReady = false;

private static void start(List<Character> characters) throws InterruptedException {
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1 + characters.size());


    for (final Character character : characters) {
        final String member = character.toString();
        System.out.println(member + " присоединился к игре");

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(member + " готовится играть");
                phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                if (!isEveryoneReady) {
                    isEveryoneReady = true;
                    System.out.println("Игра началась!");
                }
                character.run();
            }
        }.start();

    }
    phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
}
}
```